# Does movies & TV adopt meta's approach to multiple answers?

Tags: discussion

See [What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice)

> When you have two distinct answers, it's better to post two different answers than to put them both into one answer.

Does Movies & TV adopt that approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, it generally does.** Providing multiple answers to a question can be fine if they are providing largely different or opposing viewpoints.

But of course, if your follow-up question, probably asked immediately after this one gets answered, will be why one of your answers got deleted then, let me tell you that it *wasn't* simply because you posted two answers. This has already been explained to you in the comments under one of your answers. If you'd taken more than 1 minute of time before running to meta to post an *extremely* broad question based on a very special answer and very special behaviour, you might have noticed that.

Comment: It just made me think of this, but it wasn't about my answers. Just wanted to know the policy, broadly.